# Vector of std::functions error

Tags: c++, g++, stdvector, std-function

I have a vector of std::functions, but it won't compile. if I do this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
vector<function> functions;
```

I get `note:   expected a type, got ‘function’`
`error: template argument 2 is invalid`. I'm compiling on g++ with `-std=c++11`. How can I get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: You want something like `vector<function<bool(int)> functions;` ?

Comment: One step at a time. How would you instantiate a single `function` object? Once you have figured that out, you can try making a vector of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) requires that you give it additional types that are needed to represent the function as template parameters (return type, parameter types). Without the template parameters `std::function` is undefined which gives you the error you have here.

So you need to figure out the types for the functions first before you try to define a vector that contains them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the *type* of function you want to keep in your vector, something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>                                                                                         
using namespace std;

vector<function<int()>> functions;

int main() {
    functions.push_back([](){ return 1; });
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
> g++ test.cpp -std=c++1y
```

Here, you're specifying that `functions` will take a `function` that takes no parameters, and returns an `int`.